# Wraping the for loop in div tag causes css not to load in jekyll blog

Tags: jekyll

Whenever I try to wrap my for loop (in the file index.html at the root directory) a div tag, the webpage does not load properly. Can anyone tell me what might cause it ? 
[image]

Comment: I guess that your file is not properly encoded. Watch your editor setup > file encoding **utf-8 no bom**.

Comment: So I solved this: I was updating the file index.html in the root directory and since it was not working I deleted it and created an index.md file and now everything is working!